# Chrome developer tools, console messages

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

In the console, I get 9 issues where 8 of them are marked in red but with no messages about 8 red issues. like in the following screen, what red marked issues mean?! [chrome dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvKkW.png)

[Here I have 92 red marked issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnnlA.png)

Comment: Click that mini-bar to open the Issues panel with the detailed info.

Comment: when clicking it, nothing happens

Comment: It should open the `Issues` panel. You can open it manually from the three-dot menu -> More tools.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to understand what red issues with no messages mean or identify, Is it a console error? then how to get it or is it a recommendation? then why it's marked red not yellow like other recommendations. I guess it may be an error on another page but I'm not sure.
the screen provided shows the red issues with no massages that I get.

Comment: when I open the Issues panel manually, nothing more would be shown @wOxxOm

Comment: Then those must be network errors, which are hidden by default: https://puu.sh/IjAJJ/4e27c2ba52.png

Comment: @wOxxOm  checking my console settings, I found that the Hide network messages option is unchecked but the shown messages don't differ if it's checked or not.

Comment: Maybe there's another setting like showing only the selected context. You can reset devtools to defaults in its settings.

Comment: only the selected context is unchecked by default, checking it would remove some of the numbered issues but won't show their messages @wOxxOm

Comment: Resetting devtools to its defaults managed to show me the hidden issues messages. Thanks @wOxxOm